# Induction on recursive problems

Tags: recursion, induction

**Let () be defined recursively as follows: (1) =  and () = (⌊n/2⌋) +   for all integers  ≥ 2, where  is an arbitrary positive constant. Prove by induction on  that () ≤ log + . (Note: ⌊⌋ is the floor function, defined as rounding down  to the closest integer that is ≤ .)**

Can anyone help me out step by step with this example?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In () ≤ log +  what is the base number of the logarithm in the formula to prove?

Comment: It's 2 @LajosArpad

Answer (score 0):

T(1) =  and T(n) = T(⌊n/2⌋) +

### We need to prove that T(n) <= c * log(2, n) + c

## Simplest proof

The T(n) = T(⌊n/2⌋) +  recursion will need ⌊log(2, n)⌋ steps to reach T(1) (because we always halve the index, which adds up into a binary logarithm)

Since we add c each time we go further down in the recursion, the ⌊log(2, n)⌋ steps amount to c * ⌊log(2, n)⌋.

So, since we have reached T(1), we have

c * ⌊log(2, n)⌋ + T(1) =

c * ⌊log(2, n)⌋ + c

and it is trivial that

c * ⌊log(2, n)⌋ + c <= c * log(2, n) + c

---

## How to prove this with induction

Since we have a division by 2 each time for the index, it is clear that if ⌊log(2, i)⌋ = ⌊log(2, j)⌋, then T(i) = T(j), because the exact parameter value is not important by itself, it is the number of steps that determines the value we multiply c with.

And, since in our condition above ⌊log(2, i)⌋ = ⌊log(2, j)⌋, the steps needed for T(i) and T(j) are exactly the same, which proves that

if i = 2^p and i < j < 2^(p + 1), then

T(i) = T(j) = c * ⌊log(2, i)⌋ + c and it is true that

c * ⌊log(2, i)⌋ + c <= c * log(2, i) + c < c * log(2, j) + c

Hence, exact equalities occur when we have a power of 2 as a parameter, while, otherwise T(j) is strictly smaller than c * log(2, j) + c

As a result, it is enough to prove that

statement(2^n) => statement(2^(n + 1))

---

T(2^(n + 1)) =

T(2 ^ n) + c =

c * log(2, 2^n) + c + c =

c * log(2, 2^n) + c * log(2, 2) + c =

c * (log(2, 2^n) + log(2, 2)) + c =

c * (log(2, 2 * 2^n)) + c =

c * (log(2, 2^(n + 1))) which, accordingly to the concept of mathematical inclusion proves our statement.